# Write a batched counter within the kafka consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a group of kafka consumers that are reading event from the kafka topic, the event has hashtags & photoID. I want to route the hashtags to multiple kafka consumers that will maintain a map of hashtags and its count and publish it to database every minute or so.

I am writing this in java. While publishing the data to the database, do I need to take a lock on the map and stop consumption and clear out the map after commiting to database.
What is the best approach to take here so that my kafka consumer does no double count .

Answer (score 0):

You should use Kafka Connect to write to a database rather than try to maintain state within consumers. Apache Pinot or Clickhouse are also good tools for such analytical queries, and offer native Kafka ingest.

Otherwise, you can use a KTable over RocksDB KV-Store rather than an in-memory map, which can distribute consumption on its own, and will not double-count.